# How can you anticipate the correct way to quote a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, reshape

There must be a pattern/rationale here, but I just can't see it.  How do you quote variables right first time?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)

# reshape2

# These work.
dcast(mpg, manufacturer ~ class, mean, value.var = "cty")
dcast(mpg, "manufacturer ~ class", mean, value.var = "cty")

# These don't.
dcast(mpg, .(manufacturer ~ class), mean, value.var = "cty")
dcast(mpg, manufacturer ~ class, mean, value.var = cty)
dcast(mpg, manufacturer ~ class, mean, value.var = .(cty))


# plyr

# These work.
ddply(mpg, .(manufacturer), summarize, mean = mean(cty))
ddply(mpg, "manufacturer", summarize, mean = mean(cty))
ddply(mpg, manufacturer ~ class, summarize, mean = mean(cty))

# These don't.
ddply(mpg, manufacturer, summarize, mean = mean(cty))
ddply(mpg, .(manufacturer), summarize, mean = mean(.(cty)))
ddply(mpg, .(manufacturer), summarize, mean = mean("cty"))
ddply(mpg, .(manufacturer ~ class), summarize, mean = mean(cty))
ddply(mpg, "manufacturer ~ class", summarize, mean = mean(cty))


# ggplot

# This works
qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)

# These don't
qplot(.(displ), .(hwy), data = mpg)
qplot("displ", "hwy", data = mpg)

p <- qplot(displ, hwy, data = mpg)

# These work
p + facet_wrap(~ cyl)
p + facet_wrap(.(cyl))
p + facet_wrap("cyl")

# This doesn't
p + facet_wrap(cyl)
```

Feel free to add any missing permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 0):

An argument format entirely depends on the function implementation. Generally the function help page describes the way you have to provide them.

Take the `ddply` function from `plyr`. The second argument is called `.variables` and is described as :

> .variables: variables to split data frame by, as ‘as.quoted’
>   variables, a formula or character vector

That's why you can input them as `.(manufacturer)` (`as.quoted` variables), `"manufacturer"` (character vector), or `manufacturer~class` (formula).

You can sometimes judge them non-consistent, but to know how to quote arguments you have to understand the way the function works and what it is expecting as input...